# How to transpile JSX correctly

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

React elements are not rendered in the browser but the code works fine in codepen.

I am trying to add React elements to an existing project whose backend is written in Go and front end is in Angular.js. 
Now, I tried using the guided steps in React's page and I had it all working as long as I am not using JSX.
When I started to use JSX with the babel CDN provided, I noticed that my browser understands that I am using React code but elements are not rendered.

I also started using another code. Same situation. Browser acknowledges React code but nothing is rendered. I tried the piece of code below in codepen and it works.

```
<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope"><div class="ng-scope">
    <p>Hello Moto!</p>
</div>

<br class="ng-scope">

<div id="root" class="ng-scope"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js" class="ng-scope"></script>
<script type="text/babel" class="ng-scope">
    class Greeting extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (<p>Hello world</p>);
        }
    }      
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Greeting ></Greeting>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
</div>
```

In codepen, I see both "Hello Moto" and "Hello World". In my app, on the other hand, I get nothing.

Am I supposed to install other things? or do I have other problems that are not obvious?

Comment: Looks like you are using a mix of React and Angular. You will likely need to use a bundler like webpack to configure the bundling and transpiling of JSX code. A really easy way to go is to use `create-react-app` : https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo I was suspecting that. But how come the code works in codepen just fine? I even changed the compiler setting from Babel to none and it still works. (also, I am using the cdn). I was trying to avoid using node.js since we are already using GoLang.